# Generating DB tables from NHibernate mapping in VS add in

Tags: nhibernate, database-schema

I have my Visual Studio add in and I would like to pull in an NHibernate configuration file and generate database tables based on it. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = CreateConfigurationWithMappings();
new SchemaExport(config).Create(writeToConsole: true, executeInDatabase: true);
```